# Detect input device type .NET

Tags: c#

I'm writing a C# application in .NET 4. In the application I have 2 text boxes - one is used for user input, the other one is used for input from USB scanner. Is there some way to detect from which device the input comes - from keyboard or scanner (the scanner sends the characters from the barcode and Enter in the end). Is there any way to achieve this. So far I've tried to catch it in the text boxes `onKeyDown` `onKeyPress` triggers but without success. I get only the characters.

I guess I have to look somewhere in the reflection but I don't find anything since 3 days.

Thanks,
Mihail

Comment: Try checking the messages you get (either dump a log from `WndProc` or use Spy++) - there might be some info in there? Although without using DirectInput a keyboard interface may simply be a "keyboard".

Comment: I think it may come down to the model of scanner - it may support features that allow such detection to occur, or it may just dumbly represent itself to windows as a keyboard. You'd need to check the specific documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The barcode scanner will usually supply characters much faster than a human can type, usually every 10 milliseconds or so. An inelegant but effective solution is override `OnKeyDown` or `OnKeyPress` and, if the last event occurred a short time ago, treat it as a sequence of characters entered by the barcode scanner.

Comment: it is a possible solution, but I want to make it a bit more dumb-user-protected. Thank you